# Firestore document not incrementing using REST API

Tags: php, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to increment my Cloud Firestore using the REST API, however the documentation is unclear as to how this works. Here is my current implementation:-

I am trying to increment the integer value 'c' by 2, so if server value stored is 10 I want it to become 12 with this. Please help.

```
{
  "writes": [
 {
        "currentDocument": {
          "exists": true
        }
      },
      {
        "transform": {
          "document": "projects/project_name/databases/(default)/documents/collection_name/user_id",
          "fieldTransforms": [
            {
              "increment": {
                "c": {
                  "integerValue": "2"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

Error I keep getting:-

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"\": Root element must be a message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"\": Root element must be a message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit: Here's the error after fixing my payload:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"writes\" at 'document': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "document",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"writes\" at 'document': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`FieldTransform` documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/Write#DocumentTransform), you must set a `fieldPath` on your JSON representation. Here's the list of possible types for union field `transform_type`:

```
{
  "fieldPath": string,

  // Union field transform_type can be only one of the following:
  "setToServerValue": enum (ServerValue),
  "increment": {
    object (Value)
  },
  "maximum": {
    object (Value)
  },
  "minimum": {
    object (Value)
  },
  "appendMissingElements": {
    object (ArrayValue)
  },
  "removeAllFromArray": {
    object (ArrayValue)
  }
  // End of list of possible types for union field transform_type.
}
```

You should remove the `fieldPath` which is `c` inside the increment:

```
  "fieldTransforms": [
    {
      "increment": {
        "c": {
          "integerValue": "2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

and change it to this structure:

```
  "fieldTransforms": [
    {
      "fieldPath": "<FieldName>",
      "increment": {
        "integerValue": "2"
      }
    }
  ]
```

And also, just want to note that `currentDocument` and `transform` should be both inside the objects of `writes`. For reference, here's the full `JSON` representation based on your given `JSON` representation above:

```
{
  "writes": [
    {
      "currentDocument": {
        "exists": true
      },
      "transform": {
        "document": "projects/project_name/databases/(default)/documents/collection_name/user_id",
        "fieldTransforms": [
          {
            "fieldPath": "c",
            "increment": {
              "integerValue": "2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the result by using the Postman:
[image]

For more information, you may want to check [Firebase REST API: Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/Write).

Comment: I have updated my question as well. Please have a look :)

Comment: @Arnav , have you followed the proper value for `"document"`? "document": "projects/`<project_name>`/databases/(default)/documents/`<collection_name>`/`<document_name>`". If so, could you also please include a complete reproducible code on your question. Just mask sensitive information if possible.

Comment: Check the screenshot I added on my posted answer above. I used Postman to test the REST API.

Comment: Oh I see. I guess your using this endpoint : `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/*/:commit`

Comment: Glad that it now worked on your end.

Comment: Hi Mark, can you please give this question a look as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71723641/invalid-jwt-signature-while-making-google-api-call