# Invalid JWT signature while making Google API call

Tags: php, firebase, rest, google-cloud-platform, jwt

I'm trying to generate an access token for my Cloud Firestore API, I keep getting this error:-

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}
```

Edit: removing urldecode from my code results in showing an invalid signature.

I want to generate an Oauth token without having the user sign in with any form of Firebase Authentication as this is not my use-case for a web app.

I have followed the documention at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account
I have only used the endpoints mentioned in the documentation.

```
<?php


$config = json_decode('service_account_key',true);

$jwt_header = '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}';
$jwt_header_cryph = urlencode(base64_encode($jwt_header));

$jwt_claim = '{
            "iss": "service_account_id",
            "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",
            "aud":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            "exp":'.(time()+3600).',
            "sub": "user_email"
            "iat":'.time().'
        }';

$jwt_claim_cryph = urlencode(base64_encode($jwt_claim));

$data = $jwt_header_cryph.".".$jwt_claim_cryph;

$binary_signature = "";

$algo = "SHA256";
openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $config['private_key'], $algo);
$jws_signature_cryph = urlencode(base64_encode($binary_signature));


$complete_request = $jwt_header_cryph.".".$jwt_claim_cryph.".".$jws_signature_cryph;

$curl_url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';

$fields = array(
    'grant_type' => urlencode('urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'),
    'assertion' => $complete_request
);

$fields_string = "";

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );


$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

 $token = json_decode($result, true);
echo($token);
```

Comment: Hi @Arnav, have you already checked if your service account key is still active? You can check it on the Console > Service Accounts > Select the service account that you're using > Click the `keys` tab. If the generated key has been expired, you need to generate another one and use the downloaded JSON file instead.

Comment: Hi, @MarcAnthonyB I just checked but it is active in the console. I had made my key yesterday so it seems to be fine but this code isn't working. Please help

Comment: It would be better to use a library that signs JWTs. This way you're less likely to make any mistakes or create security issues in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use **urlencode**. That step is not performed on HTTP headers and breaks the base64 encoding. The signature verification is performed on the data you passed and not after URL decoding.

[Link](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/) to a Python example that I wrote so that you can compare your code. Use the Python code to see what each step generates.

You can validate an access token by calling these endpoints:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
```

The first endpoint returns information about the access token.

The second endpoint requests an OIDC Identity Token. This will be useful in the future when you work with other Google Cloud services that require identity-based authorization.

Comment: Hi John, I did see your code however is it possible for you to provide a php based solution to this? Also, the endpoints mentioned in the google cloud documentation is different from the one you have written in the answer, so i'm confused which one to use

Comment: @arnav - Did you make the change I recommended? If you did then update your question to show the current code and problem. There are several endpoints that you can call. My code works. Verify yourself and then follow my example. I do not have a PHP example. However, porting Python to PHP at this level is simple.

Comment: Can you please let us know if the above comment helps you?

Comment: What can I use instead of urlencode?

Comment: @Arnav Why do you think you need urlencode?

Comment: @JohnHanley Not using urlencode causes the signature to be invalid. As for the endpoints for my use-case it only works with the one present here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

Comment: I have updated my questions, but there's nothing different in your python code and in my php code. Still it returns the same error.

Comment: urlencode is mentioned in the documentation, please have a look - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest

Comment: @Arnav - Only for **grant_type**. The JWT is **not** urlencoded.

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried that as well, but still doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: This code works with the GA Analytics endpoint and even generates a token, but isn't working with oauth2.0

Comment: @Arnav - Show the GA Analytics code that works with your token. Your code corrupts the signature so it will not work with Analytics either.

Comment: Exact same code, but with the endpoint https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token